# How to redirect page to my site after buyer success payments on paypal.com page?

Tags: paypal

How to redirect page to my site after buyer success payments on paypal.com page

on my site , after buyer success payments on paypal.com page, it's will be countdown for 10 sec. then redirect page.

But on name.com , after buyer success payments on paypal.com page, it's will be then redirect page instance.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Name.com is using a different PayPal payment product.

With basic Website Payments Standard (WPS), you send the user to PayPal's website where they make the payment; PayPal then informs the user that they have paid before redirecting the user back to you. Because integrating WPS is so easy (it can be done in 30 seconds) and PayPal has no control over the website the buyer is being returned to, they want to be sure the user is informed that the payment has been made before sending the user back.

Name.com is probably using Express Checkout (EC), where the buyer logs into PayPal and agrees to make a payment but the payment is not actually completed until name.com makes another API call (DoEC). In that case the customer is already back at name.com before the payment API call so PayPal cannot show the buyer a "success" page. So PayPal uses slightly different language on their agreement page and leaves the seller responsible for the success page.